# File manipulation in Django models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a Django app that saves an .stl file passed using a formulary and my goal is to open the file, extract some information with a script that is already tested, and save this information in the same register that the file.

I am doing this:

```
from stl import mesh # numpy-stl library
def informationGeneration(stl_route, *args, **kwargs):
    # scripts that generates the information 
    myMesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file(stl_route) # here the error appears
    return myMesh.areas.shape[0]

class Piece(models.Model):
    """Piece model."""
    # ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='pieces/files', default='NA')
    # ...
    information = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overriding the save method."""
        self.information = informationGeneration(self.file)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        # ...
```

The problem is that when I try to save a new instance, numpy-stl detects an error, `self.file` is not the .stl file, is an alement of the formulary.

Then, I use a form:

```
class PieceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Pieces model form."""
    class Meta:
       """Form settings."""
       model = Piece
       fields = ('file')
```

How can I pass the file and not the route?

Comment: Can you try post_save signals? Or try accessing the value `self._loaded_values['file']` instead of `self.file`?

Comment: It says that my model has no attribute  ```_loaded_values```.

Comment: Show us the code where you create the `Piece` object in the first place, the one that assigns the file. Is it a view processing a POST request? The code you're showing doesn't give us any clue. Also show us `informationGeneration`. Note that `self.file` is a [`FieldFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile). It's definitely not just a path.

Comment: Updated with more info

Answer (score 1):

`Piece.file` is not a path, it's a `models.FileField`. To get the path, you have to use `self.file.path`.

Just beware that if there's actually no file for this field, `self.file.path` will raise an exception (ValueError, "the file attribute has no file associated with it"), so it's better to test before. `models.FileField` have a false value in a boolean context, so you want:

```
if self.file:
    self.information = informationGeneration(self.file.path)
```

A couple notes:

1/ a function is an action, so it's name should be a verb (ie "extract_informations")

2/ you probably don't want to re-parse the file's content each and every time your object is saved, only when the file has changed. You can use a md5sum (stored in the model) to check this.

3/ I have not double-checked but I really dont think you should use a default for this field - if you want to make it optional, use `blank=True` and `null=True`.

Comment: I've used the ```self.file.path``` but now the problem is diffent, the error that says that there is no piece in this paht, but the strange part of this is the route, it is: ``` C:\\Users\\mgijon\\Desktop\\proyect\\media\\sample_file.STL```.

Comment: @ManuelG. if it's a different problem it's a different question - and you will have to post much more details in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: It is not a different problem, is the resoult of the solution you have proposed and anything more except the change you suggest in the first line of your answer has been changed. The problem is exactly the same, it has not changed. In any case, if it is considered as a different question I will open another post.

Comment: It IS a different problem, and you actually  aknowledged this in your first comment. Your original question was about why `self.file` returned "an element in the formulary" (actually: "a models.FileField instance") instead of the uploaded file path, and I answered this question - which you could have answered yourself by just reading the doc.  Now you have _another_ error (which is not properly described so no one can help you on it) and what seems to be a question about where your file was uploaded. If you want help on those points, post a new question __with all the relevant informations__.